# Is there any blockchain explorer available to track the trades of cryptocurrency exchange?

Tags: exchanges

I haven't seen any decentralized exchange that provides the information of trades and can track the record of transaction history and time.
I am looking forward to that exchange which can provide blockchain explorer. Because it is difficult to identify the trading volume without having the blockchain explorer.

Comment: Trades inside exchanges are not Bitcoin transactions; there is no equivalent action observable on the blockchain. Most exchanges do provide trade data, but it's published as just sequences of trades.

Answer (score 1):

Trades on Bisq (a decentralized exchange) take place on-chain and are published here: https://bisq.network/markets/

Answer (score -1):

I think many exchanges provide the history and time record of trades, yeah the question is there no completely decentralize exchange exist for now . Lets see can we have any decentralize exchange in future .